# Setting up Adafruit PDM with Rapsberry Pi 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, adafruit-circuitpython

I am relatively new to working with Raspberry pi, Adafruit products and python coding. I have been working on setting up a Adafruit PDM Microphone connected to my RPi 4 and am attempting to running it on python 3. Adafruits tutorials have been amazing so far but I am having some issues getting all the required modules and libraries installed for this one. Is there a way to install Adafruit_zeroPDM and Adafruit_zeroDMA into python? I followed the github download links and tried several methods for installing them using pip3 however I am repeatedly getting errors about missing modules that should be in Adafruit's circuit python library. Is the Adafruit PDM microphone not compatible with RPi?

I have been using the following python code, which is directly taken form the adafruit website(https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pdm-microphone-breakout/circuitpython):

```
import time
import array
import math 
import board
import audiobusio

def mean(values):
    return sum(values) /len(values)

def normalized_rms(values):
    minbuf = int(mean(values))
    samples_sum = sum(
        float(sample - minbuf) * (sample - minbuf)
        for sample in values
    )
    
    return math.sqrt(samples_sum / len(values))

#Main program 
mic = audiobusio.PDMIn(board.TX, board.D12, sample_rate=16000, bit_depth=16)
samples = array.array('H', [0] * 160)

while True:
    mic.record(samples, len(samples))
    magnitude = normalized_rms(samples)
    print((magnitude,))
    print("Decible Quired")
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

I am unable to solve a library and module problem. I have downloaded Adafruit_circuitpython library and Adafruit_Blinka library as well as the required Adafruit_ZeroPDM and Adafruit_ZeroDMA however I keep getting the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audiobusio'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this too.
According to Adafruit support: "The RasPi doesn't do PDM very well."
see last comment on this locked thread:
https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=186884